# Why does Mailgun keep dropping my emails in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun, laravel-5.5

My application is using Laravel and I'm trying to send email with Mailgun. It's running locally on Apache with Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS but I've put it online and I got the same result.
I have a custom command that sends the email, like so:

```
Mail::to(User::find(1))->send(new TermEnded());
```

The command also does some other stuff which works fine. In the Mailgun dashboard I can see that all my emails are being dropped.
*My config/mail.php file:*

```
return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'postmaster@my.domain.is.here'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Name'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

];
```

*My config/services.php file:*

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

*My .env file:*

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=postmaster@my.domain.is.here
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Name"
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=my.domain.is.here
MAILGUN_SECRET=My private API key is here
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check what the User::find(1) part returns, should only be an e-mail I think.

-KlasgenootSaidHi :-)

Comment: It returns a User object but according to Laravel documentation the **to** method will automatically take the name and email properties of the object, the **to** method also takes an email adress as a string which I've tried with the same result so I don't think that line is the problem
Haha dag Robbert :D

Comment: Maybe u could post the error the mailgun dashboard gives , provides some extra information :)

Comment: There's no error message, mailgun just drops all the mails i send https://i.imgur.com/AuJVvws.png

Comment: if you're on a test domain, check the authorized recipients, if that's all ok , I have no further explenation for it ^^, not 1 email dropped during my whole testing period for me :P lmk if u found a fix :-)

Comment: I switched from Mailgun to Sparkpost and now it works fine